# How to store data in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a small game in Unity, I have an achievement system and  I want to save data of all achievements.

I wanted to make a Json file and store all the achievements details and parse the Json, but since I can't add a custom file in unity editor, maybe there is alternative to save such data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Unity. You just have to create file and save data into it.

Comment: I just want to know if there is another better approach from unity instead of using json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity)

Comment: @AbdellahSabiri Json is just one from infinities number of format which you can use.

Comment: This video is for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOjd_qU2Ido